# When to use parentheses, brackets, and curly braces in Javascript and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a bit confused when using some of parentheses, brackets, and curly braces in Javascript and jQuery. Is there a simple way of understanding when to distinguish when to use these?

Example 1:

```
$("#theDiv").animate({width: "500px" }, 1000);
```

Example 2:

```
$("img").attr({src: "/images/hat.gif", title: "jQuery"});
```

Example 3:

```
$('a[rel="nofollow self"]')
```

Thanks.

Comment: Reading the jQuery docs will explain how to use the various formats of .animate and .attr. Example 3 is an example of an attribute selector.

Comment: I kinda like this elementary question. But yeah, it's hard to answer definitively and I think @g.d.d.c gets it right: When appropriate.

Answer (score 23):

Unfortunately, the best answer is "use them each as appropriate where necessary".

Parenthesis `()` in JavaScript are used for function calls, to surround conditional statements, or for grouping to enforce Order of Operations.

```
function myFunc() {
  if (condition1) {

  }
  if ( (1 + 2) * 3) {
    // very different from (1 + 2 * 3)
  }
}
```

Braces `{}` are used during the declaration of Object Literals, or to enclose blocks of code (function definitions, conditional blocks, loops, etc).

```
var objLit = {
  a: "I am an Object Literal."
};
```

Brackets `[]` are *typically* mostly used for accessing the properties of an Object (or the elements of an Array), so `mylist[3]` fetches the fourth element in the Array.

```
var mylist = [1,2,3,4];
alert(mylist[2]);
```

It doesn't help that you're trying to start with jQuery, which also uses its own Selector Grammar within Strings that are passed to function calls (which can make it *look* much more complicated than it actually is).  This:  `$('a[rel="nofollow self"]')` is only a single function call, and the inner brackets are handled by jQuery.

Comment: What about other cases like `7 === 7 && (foo(), bar(), baz())`? What are the parens doing there?

Comment: How do we know when braces describe object literals and when they fence out blocks of code?

Comment: It can be a tad bit confusing, but in that example, `()` is being used to call three separate functions (stored as variables) in consecutive order, and `(statement, statement, statement)` returns whatever `baz()` returns, as it is the last statement in the list