# When should I use curly brackets in javascript? In general

Tags: javascript

When using javascript I never really know when to use curly brackets. I just seem to guess. How can I be sure of when I need to use them or don't need to use them? Please answer so a beginner like myself can easily understand.

These are curly brackets:   {}

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use parentheses, brackets, and curly braces in Javascript and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23225375/when-to-use-parentheses-brackets-and-curly-braces-in-javascript-and-jquery)

Comment: The general idea is that they're used for group up lines of code for "control flow" statements (like `if-else`s, `for-loop`s), function definitions, and object literals. It's also worth mentioning that the _indentation_ (the spaces or tabs before each line) is purely personal preference, and used for readability. Normally each time you start a new "block" with a curly brace, you'll add a tab or some spaces to the lines inside that block so you can see at a glance which lines are inside the block and which are not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Curly brackets are used to denote a block of code. These are generally used while writing control flow statements, loops, functions etc.

For example:

```
for ( var index = 0; index < 10; index++ ) {
    //this will contain some lines of code
}

function doSomething() {
    //this will have a set of statements
}

if ( expression ) {
    //some statements to execute if condition is true
} else {
    //Statements to execute if condition is false
}
```

Javascript object literal notation also uses curly brackets.

Example:

```
var personObject = {firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe"};
```

Answer (score 0):

Curly braces are required around object literals and functions. The are also required around conditional statements that are more than a single line of code. You can omit them around single line conditional statements, but it is good practice (and good for readability) to use them in all cases, in my opinion.

In newer ES6 code you can omit curly braces when writing a single statement arrow function.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, as in most languages, curly braces are used to enclose a block of code. It does involve simply memorising the specific places to some extent, but you can use this as a quick-reference.

They're used for control flow:

```
for(var i=0; i<someArray.length; i++) {

}

if(someCondition) {

} else {

}

//you could also write the above "if" like so, it's personal preference:

if(someCondition)
{

}
else
{

}
```

They're used for function definitions (to define the start and end of the function's code):

```
function(parameter1, parameter2) {

}
```

They're used to define object literals (this syntax can be a bit confusing to a beginner):

```
var iAmAnObject = {
    iAmAPropertyOfThatObject:42
}

//which you could also do like this:

var iAmAnObject = {};
iAmAnAObject.iAmAPropertyOfThatObject = 42;
```